# Http Response Header expiration time

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

Good morning from Santo Domingo
What is the best time to set in the expire web content ? 7 days , 1 month ?

[image]

Comment: That depends on when your content will expire.

Comment: How do I know when my content will expire ?

Comment: www.colonialtours.com.do

Comment: That's up to you.  You need to understand how HTTP caching works.